# Prevent ransomware by granting file access permission to certain processes?

Tags: windows, permissions, filesystems

One of my coworker got ransomware in his computer today (The antivirus program didn't help). All the document files were encrypted and considered to be gone forever.

So, could the ransomware be prevented by granting file access permission of *certain* file types to *certain* processes with *certain* command lines only? Then when the malicious program gets in the computer, it may not be able to encrypt the files because of no permissions?

For example: For DOCX file type, only the process with path **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINWORD.EXE** can open this file type (perhaps even checking for the EXE file's signature, hash value..etc to verify that the process is actually genuine)

Can anybody tell me if this is technically possible or not, or in other case please explain to me why it is just another dumb idea?

Comment: No;  Your idea has several flaws.  Most ransomware is delivered throw the browser not in document and video files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows stores file access permissions based on username and not process id, or extension name.

For either to be successful one needs to run as a Standard User and manually **Run as** for the limited time admin permission are needed.

**I include the below for completeness and to demonstrate how time consuming/awful the processes are.**

The closet thing you could do is this:
1. Run as a Standard/Limited User.
2. Create a new admin account
3. Change ownership to that account for all the users files and make sure it is the only account that has permissions to write to the files.  Make sure to remove Administrator,Administrators, and SYSTEM, or make the file read-only for them.

4. Shift Right Click and "Run as" the new users when attempting to run any program.

The above process is so tedious that anyone who starts this process will give up within days.

An alternative approach which may or may not work depending on the user.
Windows has the ability to create a whitelist with hash for programs that will run.  However setting it up will take a long time as every valid EXE will have to be listed individually.

Fire up the editor by typing secpol.msc in the run dialogue and navigating to **Application Control Policies** and then **AppLocker** and **Executable Rules**

Right Click and **Create Executable Rules** and **Next** and select the users you want to allow.  Then **File Hash** and **Next** then **Browse Files** and set each program one at a time.  You may give it a name and a comment by clicking **Next** or just click **Create**.

Say (Temporarily) **Yes** to create the default rules for use to delete later.  The system will become unusable without them.

After listing every conceivable EXE in **Windows** folder and **Program Files** and **Program Files(x86)** your work is just beginning.

There are 3 more areas you need to do manual rules for **Windows Installer Rules**, **Script Rules**, and **Packaged app Rules**.

Now that you have manually created 100's if not 1000's of rules manually you can delete the default permissions.

You need to add a rule to the end of the list to deny *.* for all users for each category.

**Bad software could easily abuse the default rules so after completing the process they need to be deleted.**

However, if there is ever a product update such as **Windows Update** the hashes will have to be redone.

This process might work, but the setup work is so overwhelming no sane person will ever attempt, or maintain it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to make another local user, for example LOCAL\OfficeUser and then set full access to your Office files only for LOCAL\OfficeUser and set Word shortcut to "Run as" this LOCAL\OfficeUser. Ransomware with your standard user account will not have access to your Office files but Word launched as LOCAL\OfficeUser will have full permission to work with your Office files ;) ...

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing file association and file permissions.  File associations tells the OS what *application* can open a file for use.  File permissions are granted to *users* at the file system level and allow/deny access to a file for reading/writing/modification/deletion and a few other categories.

Ransomware does not need to open an application (like MS Word) to encrypt your Word file.  All it needs is the file system permissions to access it.  Ransomware uses the current *user's* file system permissions to read the file, encrypt it using its own methods, then write the file back to the hard drive.  Ransomware will use that user's file permissions to access the local hard drive, as well as probe networked resources, to encrypt data on the machine and across the network.  Even if the user isnt an admin of the machine or network, that user's file and network access permissions might give the ransomware access to data all across the network.

This type of malware can be very destructive if you dont have backups, as you are at the ransomware developers mercy.  If you have good backups, you hopefully can restore all of your data to pre-ransomware states.

Comment: No I didn't mean that the ransomware needed to open Microsoft Word to encrypt the file. I meant that, I want to leave only MS Word to be able to open the DOCX file type, other program or process wouldn't have such permission.

Comment: @Teiv Again, if the current user has fille access to the docx file, then the ransomware does as well